# Broken Pipe while trying to upload large file retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartform-data, retrofit2, android-networking

I am getting following exception in between of upload when trying to upload a large video file(~140mb) with using retrofit 2.0. Small files are going through fine.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0xb924ef28: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
at          com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:771)
at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:80)
at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:46)
at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSink.write(Http1xStream.java:286)
at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
at okio.RealBufferedSink.writeAll(RealBufferedSink.java:104)
at okhttp3.RequestBody$3.writeTo(RequestBody.java:118)
at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBody.java:171)
at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeTo(MultipartBody.java:113)
at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:704)
at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:563)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:241)
at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
```

here is how I am creating multipart/form data

```
File originalFile = new File(attachment.getFilePath());
    RequestBody requestFile
            = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), originalFile);
    MultipartBody.Part body
            = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", attachment.getUuid(), requestFile);
    Call<ResponseBody> call
            = FileAPIProvider.getService().upload(attachment.getUuid(),
                                        attachment.getUuid(),
                                        attachment.getMimeType(),
                                        body,
                                        attachment.getVirtualPath());
```

Retrofit adapter setup

```
        builder.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    builder.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    builder.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    // Add headers
    builder.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            String token = LocalStorage.getInstance().getToken();
            request = request.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", token)
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

        sRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.FILE_URL)
            .client(builder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

I am pretty sure that my network connection is stable enough.

Comment: the problem looks to me like server closing the connection on u.
did you try your code with a  dummy non https service (local one) like netcat to see where the issue is ?

Comment: @codeScriber yeah.. That was probably it.. Server had a post body size limit around 60MB.. I had to switch to some other task I couldn't test it properly.

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal I want to use retrofit for one of my project so is it working with large file upload because i want to do same?

Comment: @Hardik yes it is, in my case problem was at server side. It works nicely.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal ok, thanks

Comment: While not entirely relevant to this question... and just in case others have client issues rather than server issues.. 
I had SSL broken pipe issue, turned out to be related to TLS 1.3 and early versions of Java 11

I'm using Apache Http Client. I changed it's connection pool configuration to use TLS1.2, excluding TLS 1.3 

I was uploading images, small images seemed to upload file, but larger images always had this problem..